# How to have a Kubernetes Pod connect to a destination only reachable by a subset of Nodes?

Tags: networking, kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes v1.13 cluster with Calico + flannel as CNI. All Nodes have a publicly routable ip address and are running Ubuntu 16.04.

Some Nodes are located in a company network, being both located in the LAN and DMZ, and therefore having access to internal services while still being publicly accessible. Others are hosted VMs at a cloud provider.

[image: Cluster]

Consider the simplified example above. I want a Kubernetes Pod to access `Internal Server C` (which is just a regular server and not part of the cluster). I could enforce the Pod to be scheduled on the internal `Node B` only, but as there is only a low latency and bandwidth required for the connection, and there is way more resources on `Node A`, I would prefer to use `Node B` just as some kind of *gateway*. (Consider several `Node B`s, so there is actually no SPOF).

My current approach is to use a DaemonSet with a Node Selector targeting all *internal* (*B*) Nodes, defining an HAProxy Pod. Those HAproxy instances can be reached as a Kubernetes Service and forward requests to the internal destination services.

Do you see a better or more straightforward way to realize the connection from a Pod located at any Node to a target that can only be reached by a subset of Nodes?

Comment: Are these web services? http(s)? or tcp services?

Comment: use ingress controller with ingress resources

Comment: @Rico they are all TCP-based

Comment: @IjazAhmadKhan how can ingress help me reach external services?

Comment: Couldn't it be done using a ClusterIP service? Or are they technically different clusters?

Comment: @BtcSources what would that service definition look like? What would you point it to? Remember the desired service is not part of the cluster (i.e. not a pod).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you say here:

> I could enforce the Pod to be scheduled on the internal Node B only, but as there is only a low latency and bandwidth required for the connection, and there is way more resources on Node A, I would prefer to use Node B just as some kind of gateway.

I think what you're looking for is an [Ambassador](http://www.cnblogs.com/pinganzi/p/7389854.html) pattern. Basically you would create this kind of containers located in your `B` zone, and your traffic would go to this containers/pods using a `ClusterIP` service since it's within the cluster.

Then, these containers would have running a **proxy** inside them (kind of what you have now on your daemons), that would route the traffic transparently to the regular server you're targeting.

Other links that may be useful could be [this from MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/ambassador) or [this slideshows (p.42)](https://www.slideshare.net/luebken/container-patterns).

If this presents a big advantage against what you have already running I'm not sure, but I do prefer to work with just pods and minimize other components if it's possible.

Comment: I think even a simple ingress controller like nginx should do the trick. You can read more about Ingress Controllers [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).

Comment: I think it may do the trick as an nginx inside these containers, but as an ingress controller I'm not sure because it's an API object aimed to control incoming connections.

Comment: @fatcook I also don't see how this helps, as ingress tends to care about connections *into*, not *out of* the cluster (I would need an *egress controller*, if that existed)...

Comment: What's the different from @muffel did?

Comment: @a.l.this solution uses `pods` and `ClusterIP` service, and muffel's one uses `DaemonSet`. They're different API Objects inside k8s and are treated in different ways inside the cluster: where they are executed, how are they run, and so forth.

Comment: @BtcSources `DaemonSet` is a higher level controller for `pods`, and I don't think use raw pods is a good practice. and muffed said "Those HAproxy instances can be reached as a Kubernetes Service" and the default service type is ClusterIP.

Answer (score 0):

If you like a network layer solution, trying this:

1. Pick one B node, find its IP address which is under the same subnet with A. Let's say this IP address `b_ip`
2. Add a route to server C(maybe a network) using `b_ip` as its gateway.

This solution has some benefit, that you don't need to modify `HAproxy`'s config when you need to visit a new service in server C.
There's something bad either, the B node you picked in step 1 would be a single point in your system.
I think you can use a floating IP as a workaround.